# Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, oracle11g

I get this error when trying to connect to an Oracle 11g database from SSIS 2008 on a laptop running Windows 7.

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine

I am stuck here: I can connect to the Oracle database using TOAD but not SSIS 2008 from the same laptop. Any help on how I might be able to resolve is appreciated.

Comment: From a command prompt, try `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /file C:\Package1.dtsx` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /file C:\Package1.dtsx` If the first one works, then yes @Steve's has hit the nail on the head

Comment: @billinkc I have removed my comment because I'm not an expert of SSIS, but this usually happens when a on a 64bit system a 64bit application try to use a 32bit driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle ole db driver is not always installed as standard when installing Oracle. Re-run your oracle installation and make sure you've installed it